# CheckListBox - Check items based on Array value - VB.NET

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, checklistbox

OK... After many many days of trying to figure it out, I have no option but to ask for help. I have Googled my little heart out and now it has led me here. PLEASE HELP.

I get a string from my MySQL database server. I then split the string and put it into an array.

Than I go through my checklistbox and see if any of the entries in there are equal to an array value. The problem is, it doesn't work and for the life of me I can't get it to work.

This is somewhat of a template I have and if anyone can help me out with this problem, I would be more than thankful.

```
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource = " + IPADDRESS + "; username = '" + USERNAME + "'; password='" + PASSWORD + "' ; database = '" + DBASE + "'")
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM hazinc WHERE title = '" + ListBox1.Text + "'", connection)

            connection.Open()

            'Command.ExecuteReader()
            Using reader As MySqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    'TextBox2.Text = reader("title")
                    STRINGRR = reader("involved")

                End While

                Dim NEWSTRINGRR As String() = STRINGRR.Split(",")

                Dim CC As Integer

                CC = 0

                For Each X In NEWSTRINGRR
                    For I = 0 To clbEmployees.Items.Count - 1
                        Try
                            If clbEmployees.Items(I).ToString() = NEWSTRINGRR(I).ToString() Then
                                SetItemChecked(I)
                            End If
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            ' MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                        End Try

                    Next
                Next



            End Using

            connection.Close()

        End Using
    End Using
```

Anyone? Please...?

Comment: Please post the contents of STRINGRR and the contents of the first 3 items in the clbEmployees

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure with so little code, but why are you using the same index for your If condition?
Then what good does X does?

I think it should be like :

```
For Each X In NEWSTRINGRR
    For I = 0 To clbEmployees.Items.Count - 1
        If clbEmployees.Items(I).ToString() = X.ToString() Then
           SetItemChecked(I)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

CMIIW.

Answer (score 0):

You do know STRINGRR is only going to have the value of the last row.   Add yes you need to post all your code.

Comment: STRINGRR contains "Your Name, My Name, Her Name," - NEWSTRINGRR contains this string broken down into an array

Comment: Did you debug those values?  Where values failed to match that you thought should match?